# Inequality between incomplete beta and gamma functions; or when is binomial distribution function above/below its limiting Poisson

Tags: probability-distributions, inequalities, special-functions, binomial-distribution

*Please note*: this question was posted first (September 4) in math.stackeschange.com and then (September 16) in stats.stackeschange.com. It got no answers in neither of those sites.

---

Let the regularized incomplete beta and gamma functions be defined as usual:
\begin{equation}
I_p(z,w) = \frac a {B(z,w)} \int_0^p t^{z-1} (1-t)^{w-1} \,\mathrm dt,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\gamma(r,t) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(r)} \int_0^t s^{r-1} e^{-s} \,\mathrm ds.
\end{equation}

Let $r \in \mathbb N$, and consider $a, b > 0$. As is well known, $I_p(r,a/p-b) \rightarrow \gamma(r,a)$ as $p \rightarrow 0$.

I have been able to prove that the difference between the incomplete beta function and its limit,
\begin{equation}
I_p(r,a/p-b) - \gamma(r,a),
\end{equation}
is positive for all $p \in (0,1)$ if $a$ is sufficiently larger than $r$, and negative if $a$ is sufficiently smaller than $r$. For example, if you have access to Matlab you can check that (note that Matlab's [`gammainc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammainc.html) uses reverse order for its arguments)

```
p = 1e-3;  r = 5; a = 10; b = 5; betainc(p,r,a/p-b) - gammainc(a,r)
```

is positive, whereas

```
p = 1e-3;  r = 5; a = 2; b = 5; betainc(p,r,a/p-b) - gammainc(a,r)
```

is negative.

I'd like to know the widest range of values of $a$ for which that difference is assured to be positive/negative.

So, my question is: Is there a known theorem that gives sufficient conditions on $a, b, r$ that assure that $I_p(r,a/p-b) - \gamma(r,a)$ is positive/negative? Even if you don't know any such theorem, any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.

---

*Alternate formulation*

Since the incomplete gamma is [related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables) to the distribution function of a Poisson random variable, and the incomplete beta is [related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) to that of a binomial random variable, the question can also be posed from a statistical point of view, as follows.

Let $B(n,p,r)$ denote the binomial distribution function (DF) with parameters $n \in \mathbb N$ and $p \in (0,1)$ evaluated at $r \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$:
\begin{equation}
B(n,p,r) = \sum_{i=0}^r \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i},
\end{equation}
and let $F(\nu,r)$ denote the Poisson DF with parameter $a \in \mathbb R^+$ evaluated at $r \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$:
\begin{equation}
F(a,r) = e^{-a} \sum_{i=0}^r \frac{a^i}{i!}.
\end{equation}

Consider $p \rightarrow 0$, and let $n$ be defined as $\lceil a/p-d \rceil$, where $d$ is a constant of the order of $1$. Since $np \rightarrow a$, the function $B(n,p,r)$ converges to $F(a,r)$ for all $r$, as is well known.

With the above definition for $n$, it is interesting to know the values of $a$ for which
\begin{equation}
B(n,p,r) < F(a,r) \quad \forall p \in (0,1),
\end{equation}
and similarly those for which
\begin{equation}
B(n,p,r) > F(a,r) \quad \forall p \in (0,1).
\end{equation}

I have been able to prove that the first inequality (in either of the two formulations) holds for $a$ sufficiently larger than $r$; more specifically, for $a$ greater than a certain bound $g(r)$, with $g(r)>r$. Similarly, the second inequality holds for $a$ sufficiently smaller than $r$, i.e. for $a$ lower than a certain bound $h(r)$, with $h(r)<r$. (The expressions of the bounds $g(r)$ and $h(r)$ are irrelevant here. I will provide the details to anyone interested.) However, numerical results suggest that those inequalities hold for less stringent bounds, that is, for $a$ closer to $r$ than I can prove.

So, I'd like to know if there is some theorem or result which establishes under which conditions each inequality holds (for all $p$); that is, when the binomial DF is guaranteed to be above/below its limiting Poisson DF. If such theorem doesn't exist, any idea or pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.